# Apps Script Histogram Chart Builder Set Max Value

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a Histogram chart in Apps script.  I am able to set the title and bucket size and get everything else working but no matter what I try I can not get the max and min range of the h-axis to set.  Code is attached below, when run the chart just has auto set for both max and min.  You will see that I have some code commented out as I have tried a range of different ways and none seem to work.

```
function buildHistogramChart() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var nameRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 3);
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 5, 3);

  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(nameRange)
    .addRange(dataRange)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.HISTOGRAM)
    .setOption('title', 'Test')
    .asHistogramChart()
    .setRange(0, 1)
    .setOption('hAxis.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')
    .setOption('histogram', {bucketSize: 0.25})
    //.asHistogramChart()
    //.setOption('histogram', {maxValue:0})

    //.setOption('xAxis', {minValue: 0,
    //                     maxValue:1})
    //.setRange(0,1)
    //.setOption('xAxis',{viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    //                  viewWindow: {
    //                  max:1,
    //                  min:0}})
    .setPosition(1,6,1,1)
    .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I have searched extensively on Google and Stack Overflow and can find no reason why at least one of my attempts is not working.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `hAxis`, instead of `xAxis`...

```
.setOption('hAxis', {
  viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
  viewWindow: {
    max:1,
    min:0
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I did that.  I'd even used hAxis elsewhere.